# Why I cannot run this script in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Guys I do really need your help. I have written few lines of code and now I am stuck because I cannot run below procedure in SQL Developer.

#### PROCEDURE

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE ROUTSETTER(
    var IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  COUNT_RECORDS NUMBER       := 0;
  BASE_TABLE    VARCHAR2(20) := 'DROGA';
  NEW_TABLE     VARCHAR2(20) := 'DROGA_COPY';
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO COUNT_RECORDS
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS
  WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
  AND OBJECT_NAME   = NEW_TABLE;
  IF COUNT_RECORDS  > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE '||NEW_TABLE;
    dbms_output.put_line('TABLE '||NEW_TABLE||' HAS BEEN TRUNCATED');
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||NEW_TABLE||' AS SELECT * FROM '||BASE_TABLE||' WHERE WYCENA = '||var;
    dbms_output.put_line('TABLE '||NEW_TABLE||' HAS BEEN CREATED');
  END IF;
END ROUTSETTER;
```

#### ERROR

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "PROJEKT.ROUTSETTER", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Comment: Do you mean you can't create it or really that you can't run it? If the latter, _how_ are you trying to run it?

Comment: Just simply: exec routsetter('IV.4');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line;

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||NEW_TABLE||
     ' AS SELECT * FROM '||BASE_TABLE||' WHERE WYCENA = '||var;
```

...puts `var` (which is a varchar) straight into an SQL statement without appropriate quoting.

If we assume `var` is free from single quotes, your line should be something like;

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||NEW_TABLE||
     ' AS SELECT * FROM '||BASE_TABLE||' WHERE WYCENA = '''||var||'''';
```

Comment: Yes! I found it is useful to print out any dynamically created SQL statements prior to call execute immediate. That helps pointing out these simple but nasty bugs.

Comment: @GeeBee Adding what commands you use to print them may be useful for others with the same problem :)